# ios use icloud with core data sqlite storage

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I have found a tutorial regarding this that I need to go through.
My question for now  is should my app provide a login screen for icloud? If not how would my app provide access to a specific icloud user?

Comment: You should probably start with [a general introduction to iCloud](http://www.appcoda.com/icloud-programming-ios-intro-tutorial/).

Comment: So what does this question have to do with core data or sqlite? You couldn't come up with a more apt title?

Comment: Matt! can I reword the question so you can open it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide a login screen for iCloud. iOS takes care of that, when the user configures a new device or when they use Settings.app to configure (or remove) an iCloud account. You have no access to the user's iCloud login information. There's only one iCloud account for the device, and it's either there or it isn't there.

The standard way to find out if iCloud is available to your app is to call `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken]` and see if the result is `nil`. If it's not `nil` then iCloud is available. You should also listen for `NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification` in case this changes.

Comment: How about if a different user logged in to the device, will they have access to the data of the first user?

Comment: @GoldenLight No, they don't. Once one user logs out, the data becomes inaccessible.

Comment: Great, let say if I released my app without icloud then later I added icloud would this be OK? Will old data be maintained? Thank you so much for your support.